# Django cannot import from app/models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django app (lets call it `app`) I have a number of files: `views.py`, `models.py` and I created my own `utils.py`.

Unfortunately, while I can include my models in my `views.py` file simply by saying

`from models import *`

In my `utils.py` file, if I try the same thing, and then work with a model, I get an exception `Global name: MyModel is not defined`. `models.py` does indeed include `utils.py`, and I understand this may be a circular dependcy, but it worked fine until I added a recent change. Is this the cause, if so is the only solution to refactor my utils file?

Answer (score 1):

Well you already know it is because of mutual dependencies. The way around it would be to split the util file in to two so, that you could avoid circular imports by separating the parts where you are required to call the models.

Also, as suggested by Mipadi instead of using a global import statement you could simply make the import in the method scope

Moreover, it would really depend how you are trying to use the models. For instance, you could access the models by "app_name.class_name" but really depends on the context in which you want to use.

Comment: Or `utils` could import `models` at a narrower scope (such as just in a function) to avoid circular dependency issues.

Comment: Oh yes..forgot to mention that